# Regex find the string after the integer

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find the string after the integers in a field but seem to get stuck on the strings part.

```
Pattern intsOnly = Pattern.compile("\d+");

1000 Stack Overflow ?                      1000 Java Developer Way
                                           1000 Spring Developer Avenue
                                           1000 Stack Overflow Road (this requested)

2000 String  ?                             2000 Integer Creek Way
                                           2000 Float Street
                                           2000 Double Trail
                                           2000 String Way (this requested)
```

The regex I have here pulls in all the 1000 and 2000 address number records from the field while I need to match at least the first string after the integers.

Requested:

```
1000 Stack Overflow Road
2000 String Way
```

Comment: What is your regex and what are you trying to match?

Comment: What is the output that you are expecting?

Comment: Trying to match on the string after the integer values.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [**How to Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Could just do `(\d+) ([a-zA-Z]+)` and get the second group that matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the string part as a group and fetch it like this:

```
Pattern.compile("\d+ ([a-zA-Z ]+)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with this regex: `\d+\s([ \w]+)`

## [Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DzZwzE/1)